Web Push Notifications_Subscription Error on Mobile Browsers
I'm using useEffect hook to call subs function to register sw (which is in the root of my proj) and
register push subscription:
const urlBase64ToUint8Array = (base64String: string | any[]) => {
        const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
        const base64 = (base64String + padding)
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
            .replace(/\-/g, '+')
            .replace(/_/g, '/');

        const rawData = window.atob(base64);
        const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

        for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
            outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        console.log(outputArray);

        return outputArray;
    };

useEffect(() => {
        const subs = async () => {
            console.log('Registering the Service Worker');
            const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', { scope: '/' });
            console.log('Registered Service worker');
            console.log('Registering Push');
            const subscription = await registration.pushManager.subscribe({
                userVisibleOnly: true,
                applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicVapidKey)
            });
            console.log('Registered push');
            await makingSubscription({ subscription })

        }
        subs()
    }, [])
}

It works Ok for desktop, but gives me error on different mobile browsers:
Subscription.tsx:68 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Registration failed - push service error
I guess there is a problem with applicationServerKey. What could be the reason and how to fix it?
